Tried to read dataframe with 6 columns, but it read a file with only one column. [R]
I tried to read a dataframe into R, but instead of 6 column dataframe I got df with one column. I used read.delim():
J68_find <- read.delim(file = "fin_tranJ68.out", header = F) 

This is what I got:
1    0  68   0  67   12925.093632

    2    0  68   0  69   12909.939633

    3    0  68   1  67   12834.338613

    4    0  68   1  69   12819.245032

    5    0  68   2  67   12744.251109

    6    0  68   2  69   12729.218646

with only one column V1.
I tried to separate this one column into 6:
J68_find <-  J68_find %>% separate(J68_find, c("Nr.",'x',"J'", "v''", "J''", "theor_exp"))

This is error I got:
Error in `separate()`:
! Can't extract column with `!!enquo(col)`.
✖ `!!enquo(col)` must be numeric or character, not a <data.frame> object.

What should I do in order to get 6 column data frame with aforementioned column names?

You need to determine what is the separator used on the file, namely whether they are tabs or a set of spaces, and adjust the delim parameter of read.delim() appropriately.

Relevant: Reading text file with multiple space as delimiter in R

Your issue is with your data file.  Without seeing your data file, we can't provide a definitive solution.

Try read.table

Using the result you've got:
text="1    0  68   0  67   12925.093632

    2    0  68   0  69   12909.939633

    3    0  68   1  67   12834.338613

    4    0  68   1  69   12819.245032

    5    0  68   2  67   12744.251109

    6    0  68   2  69   12729.218646"

...and read.table (as suggested in a comment):
read.table(text=text)

And this will give you the desired output:
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5       V6
1  1  0 68  0 67 12925.09
2  2  0 68  0 69 12909.94
3  3  0 68  1 67 12834.34
4  4  0 68  1 69 12819.25
5  5  0 68  2 67 12744.25
6  6  0 68  2 69 12729.22

The simplest way is, of course, to read your file directly with data.table.
